# Skip a Specific npm Package on Build Definition on ADO

Tags: npm, azure-devops, build, build-definition

There are some packages that I'd like to skip on build definition. I was wondering if there's any way to skip any specific npm packages on the build definition on ADO?
[image]

For example, if I want to ignore the npm package of `@microsoft/applicationinsights-common`, can I do something like below in the npm

```
install --ignore @microsoft/applicationinsights-common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possiblity to ignore one specific npm package using `npm install`.

If you want to skip such npm packages, that are only needed for development, than in `package.json` move the development specific dependencies to `devDependencies` and use `npm install --production` command to install the packages that are defined in `dependencies`.